# React-Router-Dom-v4 version of this code?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have this code I've been trying to convert to react-router-v4. The idea is that the App component is rendered always and then whatever tab I'm currently active on will change (render) the view inside the rendered App. I am having a bit of trouble converting this and would really appreciate some help.

This previously worked on react router v3. I have an idea that the IndexRoute should be changed to a Route as I am almost certain it has been depreciated to an exact route path, but as for the nested Routes I have no clue, this was my closest attempt.... followed by the React-router-v3 version that used to work.

```
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="dashboard" exact component={AsyncDashboard} />
      <Route path="input" exact component={AsyncInput} />
      <Route path="calendar" exact component={AsyncCalendar} />
      <Route path="dropdown" exact component={AsyncDropdowns} />
      <Route path="range-picker" exact component={AsyncRangePicker} />
      <Route path="chart" exact component={AsyncChart} />
      <Route path="layout" exact component={AsyncLayout} />
  </BrowserRouter>
```

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute exact component={AsyncDashboard} />
      <Route path="dashboard" exact component={AsyncDashboard} />
      <Route path="input" exact component={AsyncInput} />
      <Route path="calendar" exact component={AsyncCalendar} />
      <Route path="dropdown" exact component={AsyncDropdowns} />
      <Route path="range-picker" exact component={AsyncRangePicker} />
      <Route path="chart" exact component={AsyncChart} />
      <Route path="layout" exact component={AsyncLayout} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of wrapping `App` in a `Route`, use it directly
- Use a `Route` with a path of `/` instead of `IndexRoute`

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <App>
    <Route path='/' exact component={AsyncDashboard} />
    <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={AsyncDashboard} />
    <Route path="/input" exact component={AsyncInput} />
    <Route path="/calendar" exact component={AsyncCalendar} />
    <Route path="/dropdown" exact component={AsyncDropdowns} />
    <Route path="/range-picker" exact component={AsyncRangePicker} />
    <Route path="/chart" exact component={AsyncChart} />
    <Route path="/layout" exact component={AsyncLayout} />
  </App>
</BrowserRouter>
```